# How do I write to a cell address which is defined as a variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I read and write values to and from `Sheets("sheet1").Range("G2")` hundreds of times in my code and would like to replace the address with a variable.

My goal is to reduce clutter in my code and simplify future changes to the program.

`Sheets("sheet1").Range("G2") = 99` 
becomes
`myVar = 99`
etc.

Here's a little sub showing what I'm trying to do:

```
Global myVar As Integer

Public Sub mySub()

'write 1 to cell G2 for reference
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2") = 1

myVar = Sheets("sheet1").Range("G2")

'returns value in cell
MsgBox myVar

'try to write 99 to cell G2
myVar = 99

'check if 99 was written to cell g2; cell g2 displays value 1
MsgBox Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G2")

End Sub
```

How can I get `myVar` to write a `99` to cell `G2`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to using an object variable. Right now, `myVar` is an Integer type.

At the top do this:

```
Global myVar As Range
```

Then change this line:

```
myVar = Sheets("sheet1").Range("G2")
```

to this:

```
Set myVar = Sheets("sheet1").Range("G2")
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of global variables. I try to limit them as much as possible. You could also write a function:

```
Public Function MyRef as Range
Set MyRef = Sheets("sheet1").Range("G2")
End Function
```

If you have multiple callsites, by using a function, you can set a breakpoint in the function where as with a Global you can't.

Just my preference.